# Racket Tree Travesal

Tags: recursion, tree, racket, traversal

I have the following problem with Racket.

I'm trying to implement tree pre-order, post-order traversal for a generic tree.

The struct definition is:

```
(define-struct eempty [])
(define-struct branch [left value right])
```

I can't use the `unless/when` operator, just `if` and `cond`.
I can't really come up with a solution. I've looked at the wikipedia pseudocode but it's not really helping due to racket programming paradigm.

```
(define (inorder tree x)
  (cond [(and (branch? tree) (branch? (branch-left tree))) (inorder (branch-left tree) x)]
        [(and (branch? tree) (branch? (branch-right tree))) (inorder (branch-right tree) x)]
```

This is what I've done until now, but it has problems when matching an `empty` struct.

Update:

What I am trying to do is display / printing node value in-order or/and post-order.

I know I have to implement (somehow) 2 more conditions:

```
(and (branch? tree) (empty? (branch-left tree))) do-something x)
(and (branch? tree) (empty? (branch-right tree))) do-something x)
```

What do I have to do in do-something? I think I'm missing this point.

Any help?

Comment: What is your _data definition_ for a tree? Is a tree always a branch? Or can it be `one of` an eempty or a branch? (I mean _data definition_ in the context of [How to Design Programs](https://htdp.org/), the textbook mentioned in John Clements' answer. The _data definition_ is the first step of the design recipe.)

Comment: A tree is a branch which left and right value can either be a branch or an eempty. Example: (define tree (make-branch (make-branch (make-branch empty 2 empty) 4 (make-branch empty 5 empty)) 10 (make-branch (make-branch empty 12 empty) 15 (make-branch empty 18 empty))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with what we have:

```lisp
#lang racket
(define-struct empty [])                     ; no fields
(define-struct branch [left value right])    ; three fields
```

We can try to make some trees:

```lisp
(define t1 (empty))
(define t2 (branch t1 7 t1))
```

Now we can try playing with it a little:

```
> t2
#<branch>
> (branch-left t2)
#<empty>
> (branch-left t1)
branch-left: contract violation
  expected: branch?
  given: #<empty>
> (branch? t2)
#t
> (branch? t1)
#f
> (empty? t2)
#f
> (empty? t1)
#t
>
```

So *that* is our repertoire. Racket's *struct* macro defines various functions for us to use -- constructors, accessors, predicates, ... .

How to print a value? Say,

```lisp
(define (display-value v)
  (display #\ )
  (display v))
```

So now we can

```lisp
> (display-value (branch-value t2))
 7
```

`empty` has no `value` field, only `branch` does:

```lisp
(define (display-tree-inorder t)
    (cond
        ((empty? t)
           (display-empty) )                       ; define it later
        ((branch? t)
           (display-branch-inorder                 ; define it later
                           (branch-left t)
                           (branch-value t)
                           (branch-right t)))))
```

In defining this, we have *followed the type*: our trees are either `empty`, or a `branch`. This *is* how *we* defined them, with those two struct definitions.

All that's left is to complete the missing definitions for `display-empty` and `display-branch-inorder`.

But before we do this, we can also have

```lisp
(define (display-tree-preorder t)
    (cond
        ((empty? t)
           (display-empty) )
        ((branch? t)
           (display-branch-preorder
                           (branch-left t)
                           (branch-value t)
                           (branch-right t)))))

(define (display-tree-postorder t)
    (cond
        ((empty? t)
           (display-empty) )
        ((branch? t)
           (display-branch-postorder
                           (branch-left t)
                           (branch-value t)
                           (branch-right t)))))
```

So what is `display-empty` doing? It does nothing:

```lisp
(define (display-empty)
    #f)
```

And what about `display-branch-inorder`?

```lisp
(define (display-branch-inorder lt val rt)
```

according to Wikipedia I'm sure, it starts by  displaying its *left* *sub-tree*,

```lisp
    (display-tree-inorder .... )
```

then it gets to display its value

```lisp
    (display-value .... )
```

and it finishes up by displaying the right sub-tree:

```lisp
    .... )
```

Same for the other two variants.

After you've done all this, you'll feel the urge to abstract, and to generalize, by following the principle of separation of concerns. Good. Our `display-tree-inorder` lumps together several things: it traverses a tree, according to this or that notion of order, and it does something with each node's value.  All these can be abstracted over and made into arguments to a generalized procedure, say, `traverse-tree`.

So you see, it's quite simple: *follow the types!* and everything will fall in line for you.

Comment: Thank a lot! This really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a 'cond' branch for the 'empty' struct. You can refer to the [How To Design Programs](https://www.htdp.org/) textbook for help on this, specifically the "template" step associated with mixed self-referential data.

Comment: Specifically, section 4.6, [Desiging with Itemizations](https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3adesign-itemization%29), which describes how to make the _template_ for a data definition that uses `one of`. And section 9, [Designing with Self-Referential Data Definitions](https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3adesign-lists%29) helps put that in the context of self-referential data like trees.

Comment: That's what I am missing. I know there must be some 2 condition more i.e (and (branch? tree) (empty? (branch-left tree)) and (and (branch? tree) (empty? (branch-left tree)). But I don't understand what should I do if those condition are true.

Comment: Ah! No, you're stuck in the "fear of null" trap. I'm guessing you have some programming experience that's causing problems for you. You should almost certainly just have an (empty? tree) branch. However, in order to answer your question better, perhaps you could add some more context to your question. What, specifically, are you trying to *do* with your pre- or post-order traversal?

Comment: I have updated my question with some more informations. Any help is appreciated!